# Change the image on hover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the image on hover but it is changing the image of all the container which has the same class. Below is the code I'm trying.

```js
$(function(){
 $(".hover-image").hide();
 $(".tile-image").on({
  mouseenter: function(){
   $(".tile-image").hide();
   $(".hover-image").show();
   
   
    },
 mouseleave: function(){
   $(".tile-image").show();
   $(".hover-image").hide();
 }
 });
 
});
```

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-tile">
      <div class="image-container primary-images">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <img class= "tile-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg">
          <img class= "tile-image hover-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.main-wrapper loops in the website

Comment: Where are the `.tile-image` and `.hover-image` elements in your HTML?

Comment: Fixed the code above

Comment: You should be using `$(this).hide()` and `$(this).show()` rather than `$(".tile-image")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$(function(){
  $(".tile-image").on({
   mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).attr('src','https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg');
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).attr('src','https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg');
  }
  });

});
```

Comment: I can't use this since the src changes dynamically and there are 100's of it.

Comment: I'll send you with dynamic source

Comment: Var source = $('.tile-image img').attr('src');  you can get source using this

Answer (score 2):

> UPDATED

You should use this:

```js
$(function() {
          $(".tile-image").on({
            mouseenter: function() {
               $(this).attr('src',$(this).data("mouseenter"));
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
              $(this).attr('src',$(this).data("mouseleave"));
            }
          });
        });
```

```html
<style>
img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
}

</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
          <div class="product">
            <div class="product-tile">
              <div class="image-container primary-images">
                <a href="https://www.google.com">
                  <img class= "tile-image"  data-mouseenter="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg"  data-mouseleave="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg"src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg">
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: this is not working as expected, some glitch
https://codepen.io/naveenborn/pen/YBvpqw

Comment: please look at my answer again @NaveenLBhandari